# How To make WordPress widget's title( In 2 color) [Diffrent Title color In Widget title]

Tags: wordpress, colors, widget, title

I would like to display WordPress widget's title in two colours.

[image]

Here's what i have tried:

```
function cn_init_widgets($id){
    register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'footer1',
    'id' => 'cn-ft-1',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="my-cn-ftr">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h5>',
    'after_title' => '</h5>',
    ));
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'cn_init_widgets');
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to get into your widget appearance >> widget and rewrite your widget title to something like

My title<\span>

Now you can target span in css and add styling to it.

Also you can add some javascript that will find your widget title and wrap second word in span. Then use javascript .style or just css